# Rounding up decimals bug in c?

Tags: c, square-root

I'm doing a very simple c program which receives the integer n and finds the square root approximation of n.

This is my square root approximation function up to the 5th decimal:

```
float sqrt_approx(int n){
    float sqrt,how_many_tenths=10,how_many_decimals=0,i;
    for (i=1;i<n;i++){
        if ((i*i)<n) continue;
        if (i*i==n){ sqrt=i; goto return_; }
        else break;
    }
    sqrt=i-1;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        if (i==9){

            sqrt=sqrt+i/how_many_tenths;

            how_many_tenths*=10;
            how_many_decimals++;
            if (how_many_decimals != 5) i=0;
            else break;
        }
        if ((sqrt+i/how_many_tenths)*(sqrt+i/how_many_tenths) < n) continue;
        sqrt=sqrt+(i-1)/how_many_tenths;
        how_many_tenths*=10;
        how_many_decimals++;
        if (how_many_decimals != 5) i=0;
        else break;
    }
    return_:
        return sqrt;
}
```

Brute force, pretty intuitive I would say. The problem, however, appears when I'm trying to get the approximation up to the 6th decimal. In order to do that, all I need to do is to change this:

```
if (how_many_decimals != 5)
```

into:

```
if (how_many_decimals != 6)
```

both times in my code. And if I'm to evaluate the square root of $35$ approximation up to the 6th decimal,
I get $5.916080$ instead of $5.916079$.

I tried to find the mistake and it appears to me that the 5th decimal gets rounded up. Take a look, I changed only a bit of my code to find out what is going on here:

```
float sqrt_approx(int n){
    float sqrt,how_many_tenths=10,how_many_decimals=0,i;
    for (i=1;i<n;i++){
        if ((i*i)<n) continue;
        if (i*i==n){ sqrt=i; goto return_; }
        else break;
    }
    sqrt=i-1;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        if (i==9){
            printf("%f + %f equals: ",sqrt,i/how_many_tenths); //NEW
            sqrt=sqrt+i/how_many_tenths; //NEW
            printf("%f\n",sqrt); //NEW
            how_many_tenths*=10;
            how_many_decimals++;
            if (how_many_decimals != 6) i=0; //NEW (6 instead of 5)
            else break;
        }
        if ((sqrt+i/how_many_tenths)*(sqrt+i/how_many_tenths) < n) continue;
        sqrt=sqrt+(i-1)/how_many_tenths;
        how_many_tenths*=10;
        how_many_decimals++;
        if (how_many_decimals != 6) i=0; //NEW (6 instead of 5)
        else break;
    }
    return_:
        return sqrt;
}
```

results in ( after typing `printf("%f,sqrt_approx(35)`):

$5.000000 + 0.900000$ equals: $5.900000$ ( which is fine )

$5.916070+0.000009$ equals: $5.916080$ ( which is not fine )

$5.916080$

What seems to be the problem here ?

Comment: float values are not dense enough to have good accuracy with more than 6 decimal places

Comment: Don’t use `float`; use `double`.  The precision of single-precision floating point is insufficient to make it work reliably.

Comment: That fixed it. Appreciated.

Comment: The square root of 35 is 5.91607978309961604256... 5.916080 is the correct approximation. 5.916079 is **plainly wrong**.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. If the square root of 35 is (lets say) 5.91607900000010001... , I would still have the same problem don't you think ?

Comment: That first loop of yours is pretty horrid, as is the `goto` in it.  Use `return i;` when you find an exact root.  If your tutor demands “single return point”, then if you don’t feel like trying to persuade them that they’re outdated in their thinking (quite possibly wise), at least note that they’re outdated. I’d far rather have multiple returns than use `goto`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know , goto is a good example of bad programming . I just wrote it in a hurry, I usually don't use it.

Comment: The square root of 35 is not 5.91607900000010001. If you want to approximate 5.91607900000010001, say so, preferably in a separate question, with code that tries to do just that.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. awww I'm sorry for hurting your feelings mate :) But that is no reason for deleting comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing float into double fixed it. Thanks for your comments guys.

Comment: Never use "float" instead of "double" unless you are able to give a good explanation why using float would be better.

Comment: @gnasher729 Makes a lotta sense now.